# Why are the data in the database not filtered?

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq

When entering dates in string format, filtering in the database using Contains should be performed, but it returns null. What could be the problem?

I compared the output String values from the database with the string entered by the user, they are absolutely identical.

```
var find = fg.Users
    .Where(r => r.CreationDate.ToString().Contains(searchclientregdate))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: is there a reason why you are casting it as string and not comparing dates directly?

Comment: What type is CreationDate of?

Comment: What values, you have in CreationDate of database & you applying value of searchclientregdate.

Comment: _but it returns null_ - your code will never returns `null`.

Comment: Your query is translated and executed as SQL. String conversions in the database are different from string conversions in .NET (which you see in the debugger for instance). If you want to see what is compared by the query, execute something `var dbCreationDates = fg.Users.Select(r => r.CreationDate.ToString()).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the string to a date and then use it in the comparison
make a conditional filtering if needed

```
DateTime.TryParse(searchclientregdate, out dateVar)



var find = fg.Users
    .Where(r => r.CreationDate<= dateVar && r.CreationDate>= dateVar)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Your decision helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If CreationDate is a DateTime or DateTimeOffset, the .ToString() method could reformat it in a different manner than expected. If CreationDate already is a string, you don't need to use the .ToString() method. Maybe it helps to specify a CultureInfo of your choice, like CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"). Passing it to the ToString will make the .ToString() method format your DateTime differently.

```
var find = fg.Users
    .Where(r => r.CreationDate.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).Contains(searchclientregdate))
    .ToList();
```

EDIT: Storing the CultureInfo beforehand, or creating a DateTime/DateTimeOffset from the input string would be another possibility.

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2